# how to solve the error(clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) )

Tags: ios

I've downloaded a sample source code from [here](http://www.rewenderlich.com), but when I open that, I'm getting the error "Clang: Error: Linker Command Failed With Exit Code 1 (Use -V To See Invocation)"